# Trying to fix warning about ‘const’ qualifier

Tags: c, pointers, struct, openssl, constants

I have been trying to use OpenSSL for retrieving secure webpages.  I have a successful program, but it compiles with the following warning:

```
warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
```

In order to understand the problem I have reduced the code to the following which achieves the same warning:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(void)
{
    SSL_METHOD *method;
    method = SSLv23_client_method();
}
```

It appears as though SSL_METHOD is a struct which is declared as a constant.

Is there a way to remove the 'const' keywork from the declaration so this error goes away?  Or do I have to find out exactly what the struct is made of and then recreate it without the 'const' keyword?

Comment: That error implies that `SSLv23_client_method` is returning a `const SSL_METHOD *`...

Comment: So I just need to declare the pointer as const.  TYVM!! worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL_METHOD expects a constant type:

```
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
```

will compile without error. See `man ssl` for example:

```
   const SSL_METHOD *SSLv2_client_method(void);
       Constructor for the SSLv2 SSL_METHOD structure for a dedicated client.
```